# JQuery ErrorUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.js:2 e.extend.map jquery.js:2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adapting some jQuery code for a project but have encountered an error which I'm unsure of how to interpret.

The error and top of stack trace are:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   jquery.js:2 e.extend.map jquery.js:2 MushraTest.createFileMapping
>   beaqle.js:590

Line 590 is and works fine for TestIdx = 0-2 but this error is thrown consistently at TestIdx = 4.

```
  var NumFiles = $.map(this.TestData.Testsets[TestIdx].Files, function(n, i) { console.log(n,i);return i;}).length;
```

Testsets are each stored in the form

```
    Testsets: Array[10]
    0: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
    3: Object
    Name: "exp04"
    files: Object
        0: "filepath/file.wav"
        1: "filepath/file2.wav"
    4: Object
    5: Object
    6: Object
    7: Object
    8: Object
    9: Object
```

Is anybody familiar with this error or able to identify what my code is doing wrong?

Comment: "this error is thrown consistently at TestIdx = 4." Your array doesn't have an index `4`, it just goes from `0` to `3` (probably).

Comment: It does. I realise my original information didn't make this clear so have edited.

Comment: The issue very much seems to be that what you're passing to `$.map()` is `undefined`, so if there's an object at index `4` said object doesn't have a `Files` property. Your question indicates there's a `files` property (lowercase F), which isn't the same thing.